# Where to find a good overview when to use which creational Design-pattern

Tags: design-patterns

I am looking for an overview to immediately figure out when to use which of the following creational patterns:

- Builder
- Factory
- Abstract Factory
- Prototype

And also when it is better to stick to a plain class.

Can you provide a good resource, or maybe explain it in a few sentences e.g. "if an object is depending on nothing, use a normal class, if multiple similar constructions are needed, then usually factory is preferred."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually refer to [OODesign](http://www.oodesign.com/)

They provide good explanation of patterns. Also there are section 'When to Use' , 'Common Usage' that help for quick reference.

Comment: Thanks, the page seems to explain patters in a good short way